# Cannot resolve method startsWith by using anyMatch

Tags: java

Can some one tell me please what is wrong here. My code is fine until I added this portion of code if (!tmp.isEmpty()) { return e.isEmpty(); }
The error is: Cannot resolve method startsWith(java.lang.String)

```
@Test
    public void TestData() {
        ArrayList<String> rootOpts = new ArrayList<String>();
        rootOpts.add("aa");
        rootOpts.add("bb");
        rootOpts.add("ac");
        ArrayList<String> allSiblings = new ArrayList<String>();
        allSiblings.add("aa");
        allSiblings.add("ac");
        allSiblings.add("abc");

        System.out.println("allMatch " + rootOpts.stream()
                .map((e) -> {
                    System.out.println("e = " + e);
                    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tmp.addAll(allSiblings);
                    String[] CHs = {"ab","aa","ac"};
                    for (String chh : CHs) {
                        tmp.remove(chh);
                    }
                    if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                        return e.isEmpty();
                    }
                    return e;
                })
                .anyMatch(v -> v.startsWith("a")));
    }
```

I am trying to rewrite the following code below(this code is contained in a method that is supposed to return a boolean value true or false):

```
for (Option e : rootOpts) {
            List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            tmp.addAll(allSiblings);
            if (e.getData() != null && !e.getData().getString().isEmpty()) {
                String[] chs = {"ab","aa","ac"};
                for (String ch : chs) {
                    tmp.remove(ch);
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

`e.isEmpty()` returns a `boolean`. In the following method `anyMatch` you want to invoke the method `startsWith` on this `boolean` but this method does not exist on `boolean`. So change your code to:

```
            if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                return ""; //or whatever string makes sense
            }
```

Comment: Adding this is not working : if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                return new ArrayList();
            }. My goal here is actually if my tmp list is not empty I am supposed to return false.

Answer (score 0):

`e` is of type `String` while `e.isEmpty()` is of type `Boolean`.

Therefore the return type of your function is `Object`.

Finally, `Object` does not have a `startsWith` function, contrary to the original `String` type that was returned which is why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the return type of `isEmpty()` - it's `boolean`. How are you planning to do `startsWith` on a `boolean true/false`? :) Stream predicts that it's possible to get boolean, and thus it cannot let you do `startsWith` on it.

```
if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
    return e.isEmpty();
}
```